# How to count the duplicated numbers of list with order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering what is the efficient way to count the duplicate numbers of list.

This is the example:

numbers = [5, 10,10,10, 15,15, 8,8,8,8]

answer = **[1,3,2,4]**

.

This is my code that I figured out... but seems inefficient.

```
answer=[]
now = numbers[0]
count=1
done=False
for n in numbers[1:]:
    if now == n:
        count+=1
        done=False
    else:
        answer.append(count)
        count=1
        now=n
        done=True
if(not done):
    answer.append(count)
if(done):
    answer.append(1)
return answer
```

Does anyone have good answer for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using the built-in [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> numbers = [5, 10,10,10, 15,15, 8,8,8,8]
>>> [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(numbers)]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
```

`groupby(iterable, key=None)` makes an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable (`numbers` in this case). The key is a function computing a key value for each element. If not specified or is `None`, key defaults to an identity function and returns the element unchanged.

Comment: While yours is probably faster (for implementational details and mostly C-optimization), one may add that from a purely algorithmic view, `sum(1 for _ in g)` should be preferred as it is also linear in time, but uses constant space.

Comment: This is fairly slow-- the second slowest of all the methods suggested here, by my count. Almost 5 times slower than my method.

Comment: @Ezra it is slower for this trivial data but with anything meaningful for example `numbers = [cell for row in [[i]*i for i in range(100)] for cell in row]` it is more than twice as fast as your method.  This answer is "generally" faster (the fastest of all the answers currently offered) and in my opinion, the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
res = {d:numbers.count(d) for d in numbers}        
print (res)
```

output:

```
{5: 1, 10: 3, 15: 2, 8: 4}
```

Comment: This is very slow-- more than six times slower than my method.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an OrderedDict to keep the result's order like this. By hashing the value, this will be fast.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
numbers = [5, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 8, 8, 8, 8]
answer = [1, 3, 2, 4]
result_map = OrderedDict()
for item in numbers:
    if item in result_map:
        result_map[item] += 1
    else:
        result_map[item] = 1
result = list(result_map.values())
print(result)
```

By the way, I you sure your list has order, you can do this to be faster.

```
result = []
last_value = None
for item in numbers:
    if last_value == item:
        result[-1] += 1
    else:
        result.append(1)
        last_value = item
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count by `dict`, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
numbers = [5, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 8, 8, 8, 8]
for n in numbers:
    result[n] += 1
print(list(result.values()))
```

Answer (score 0):

A comparison of my method and a few others suggested here:

```py
from itertools import groupby
import timeit
from collections import defaultdict


numbers = [5, 10,10,10, 15,15, 8,8,8,8]

def manual():
    count = 1
    previous = numbers[0]
    out = []
    for number in numbers[1:]:
        if number == previous:
            count += 1
        else:
            out.append(count)
            count = 1
            previous = number
    out.append(count)
    return out

def built_in():
    return [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(numbers)]

def dict_count():
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for n in numbers:
        result[n] += 1
    return list(result.values())

def henro_method():
    res = {d:numbers.count(d) for d in numbers}        
    return res

print("'Manual' method average time:", timeit.timeit(manual, number=10000))
print("Built-in 'itertools' method average time:", timeit.timeit(built_in, number=10000))
print("'dict_count' method average time:", timeit.timeit(dict_count, number=10000))
print("'henro_method' method average time:", timeit.timeit(henro_method, number=10000))
```

Result:

```
'Manual' method average time: 0.013817799999999998
Built-in 'itertools' method average time: 0.0379492
'dict_count' method average time: 0.06737080000000001
'henro_method' method average time: 0.08482129999999999
```

So far `manual()` is the best, which doesn't surprise me: it's linear time.

Comment: Your method "seems" fastest for this trivial data but if performance is important try your test again with `numbers = [cell for row in [[i]*i for i in range(100)] for cell in row]`.  You will see that it is no longer the fastest and that `itertools` is more than twice as fast.